# Does Hex / Hexblade's curse end the spell Time Stop?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock, curses

*Time stop* states:

> This spell ends if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that you create during this period, **affects a creature** other than you or an object being worn or carried by someone other than you.

Hex states:

> You place a curse on a creature that you can see within range. Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 necrotic damage to the target whenever you hit it with an attack. **Also, choose one ability when you cast the spell. The target has disadvantage on ability checks made with the chosen ability.**

Hexblade's Curse states:

> ... **The target is cursed for 1 minute**. The curse ends early if the target dies, you die, or you are incapacitated. Until the curse ends, you gain the following benefits:
> You gain a bonus to damage rolls against the cursed target. The bonus equals your proficiency bonus.
> Any attack roll you make against the cursed target is a critical hit on a roll of 19 or 20 on the d20.
> If the cursed target dies, you regain hit points equal to your warlock level + your Charisma modifier (minimum of 1 hit point).
> You can't use this feature again until you finish a short or long rest.

My confusion is on what "affects a creature" means here. My best guess would be that Hex would end *time stop*, since it causes a mechanical effect on the target creature (see bolded). However, Hexblade's Curse would not end *time stop*, since all the mechanics just affect the caster. I'm curious if there is a more concrete idea of what "affects a creature" actually means.

Answer (score 7):

#### You cursed the target, so you affected them.

This seems pretty straightforward to me. “Affect” has no special meaning in the rules, so I consulted an English dictionary (Cambridge):

> affect: to have an influence on someone or something<sup>1</sup>

If you curse the target, you have affected them, and *time stop* ends.

---

<sup>1 It doesn’t really matter what dictionary you consult, every definition of “affect” will make it clear that placing a curse on the target that makes them weaker counts as “affecting” the target.</sup>

Comment: Hi Thomas, I will remove my answer, we are essentially saying exactly the same thing, and you did it a bit faster.

Answer (score -3):

### Your interpretation is correct

*Hex* affects the target.
*Hexblade’s Curse* affects *you* (with respect to the target).

Comment: “The target is cursed”: seems like it affects the target.